# Selectize : Change settings dynamically

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

I having difficulties to find a way to change settings of selectize on the fly

On the upper parts of my js, I have initiated my selectize like this :

```
    var selectize = $('select').selectize({
    .... others params...,
    .... others params...,
    load: function(query, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://sample.com/test1", // Old remote url
            type: 'GET',
            data : {
                search : query
            },
            dataType : "json",
            error: function() {
                callback();
            },
            success: function(results) {
                if(results.data == undefined){
                    callback();
                }else{
                    callback(results.data); 
                }
            }
        });
    }
})[0].selectize;
```

At some point, i need to change the url of the selectize on click of the button. I tried the codes below.

```
selectize.clear();
selectize.clearOptions();
selectize.load(function(callback) {
    this.settings.url = "http://sample.com/test2";  // New remote url
    $.ajax({            
        url: this.settings.url,
        success: function(response) {
            callback(response.data);
        },
        error: function() {
            callback();
        }
    })
});
```

Option is updated but the url still the same. When the user type on search box, the search query uses the old URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully found a solution but its a little bit messy.

```
selectize.settings.load =  function(query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://sample.com/test2", // NEW remote url
        type: 'GET',
        data : {
            search : query
        },
        dataType : "json",
        error: function() {
            callback();
        },
        success: function(results) {
            if(results.data == undefined){
                callback();
            }else{
                callback(results.data); 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I hope someone can find a better solution other than this. It would be better if this is existing on the docs of selectize.